# SQL query to combine tables without joining

Tags: sql

SQL Joins seem to always merge the data, but I need to create a report of distinct tables which share a column name. So for all values in one table, all the values of the other table will be blank and vice-versa. See attached

[image: example diagram].

P.S. Still a novice - would really appreciate any help to word this question/title more properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `UNION ALL`

```
select project, null as milestone, null as change
from projects
union all
select project, milestone, null as change 
from milestones
union all
select project, null as milestone, change
from changes
```

The difference between `union` and `union all` is that the latter does not remove duplicate rows in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your results, you seem to want:

```
select p.project, null as milestone, null as change
from projects p
where not exists (select 1 from milestones m where m.project = p.project) and
      not exists (select 1 from changes c where c.project = p.project)
union all
select m.project, m.milestone, null as change 
from milestones
union all
select c.project, null as milestone, c.change
from changes;
```

This is because your results do not have the row:

```
A     NULL     NULL
```

So you seem to only want a row from `projects` when there is no corresponding row in the other tables.